# Spring RESTful web service POST object

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, gson

I'm experiencing troubles with Spring and Gson to POST my object to the server. I get a result back which is empty, even though it contains data.

This code snippet is from on the Restful web service:

```
    @RequestMapping("/summe")
    public @ResponseBody String summe(ArrayList<ServiceSettingsListItem> list) {
    return "Greeting.summe() = <" + list + ">" + list.size();   
}
```

My client:

```
    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(new 
File("demo.json").toPath()));
    ServiceSettings serviceSettings = gson.fromJson(fileContent, 
ServiceSettings.class);
    String baseUrl = serviceSettings.getUrl();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.postForObject(baseUrl, serviceSettings, String.class);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static class ServiceSettings {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ServiceSettings [url=" + url + ", test=" + test + ", items=" 
    + items + "]";
    }

    private String url;
    private int test;
    private ArrayList<ServiceSettingsListItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public int getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(int test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public ArrayList<ServiceSettingsListItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<ServiceSettingsListItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}

public static class ServiceSettingsListItem {
    private String name;
    private int value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

}

And here is my JSON:

```
{"url":"http://localhost:8080/summe",
"test":123,
"items":[
 {"name":"name1","value":5},
 {"name":"name1","value":6}
 ]
}
```

I expect to get a result of two but the result says it's 0.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of POSTing `ServiceSettings` object, you need to post `items` element of it as the controller expects the payload to be a list. Try the following:

```
ServiceSettings serviceSettings = gson.fromJson(fileContent, ServiceSettings.class);
String baseUrl = serviceSettings.getUrl();
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(baseUrl, serviceSettings.getItems(), String.class); //Assuming there is a getter for items
```